# How to mock lambda with mockito in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I have a kotlin Android app. There is a function that loads compositions from the backend and returns them to a callback:

```
getCompositons(callback: (Array<Composition>) -> Unit)
```

How can I mock the callback using mockito. So that I then can do something like this:

```
var callback = //mockito mock
getCompositons(callback) 
verify(callback, timeout(10000)).apply()
```

I read that lambda are matched to the java type function and therefore I assume apply could be the method invoked. Maybe I could mock a function and use that? But the Kotlin function interface only seems to have one return type, no parameters. java.util.Function says unresolved reference function.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why would you bother mocking it instead of writing a function that does its own verification?

Comment: Mockito takes care of waiting for the result, since it comes async. If I had to do that myself I would have to use some futur object or maybe wait and notify.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is really no different to mocking any other type:

```
val callback = mock<(Array<Composition>) -> Unit>()

getCompositons(callback)

verify(callback)(any())  // Or verify(callback).invoke(any()) to be explicit
```

*(In case you weren't aware of them, I'm using the [mockito-kotlin bindings](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) here.)*

Comment: Oh interesting library. I'll try that one after dinner thanks. because without the library that doesn't work^^

Comment: @findusl - That's fair, I've been using this library for so long I've forgotten what life was like without it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```
val function: Array<Composition>) -> Unit = {}
val callback = mock(function::class.java)

getCompositons(callback)

verify(callback)(any()) // or for example verifyNoInteractions(callback)
```

No extra libraries besides the standard mockito are needed

Comment: I tried this but got "Cannot mock/spy class MyTest$myTestMethod$function$1. Mockito cannot mock/spy because :- final class" The error occurs at the second line of your code snippet. Basically it seems the class which Kotlin assigns to such callbacks is a final class

Answer (score 0):

I solved here mocking the callback like this:

```
  private val onNewUrl: (url: String) -> Boolean = mock {
    on { mock(any()) } doReturn true
  }

  verify(onNewUrl).invoke(any())
```