# Mockito: Mock an invokable param

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

Kotlin function to test:

```
suspend fun <T: Any> handleSomething(call: suspend () -> Result<T>) {

    if (call.invoke() == "Something") {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to mock **call** here. 
Usually I mock like:

```
val call = Mockito.mock(SomeClass::class.java)
```

But I don't know for param as function like this

Answer (score 1):

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306974/11377112

This is how you mock a lambda function:

```kotlin
val call = Mockito.mock<suspend () -> Result<T>>()

handleSomething(call)

verify(call)()
// Or verify(call).invoke(any()) to be explicit
```