# How to use mockito to test that callback is invoked with Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, callback, mockito

I have a Kotlin class that takes a callback, as follows:

```kotlin
class MyKotlinClass (private val handleSomeCallBack: (ByteArray) -> Unit) {
    private val someBuffer = BytesBuilder()

    fun myFunction(bytesList: List<Byte>) {
        handleSomeCallBack(someBuffer.toArray())
    }
}
```

I can’t quite figure out how I can use Mockito with jUnit to test that the callback is invoked.

I feel that I should be using an `argumentCaptor` as opposed to a spy, but am not quite sure.

What I have currently is as follows:

```kotlin
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyKotlinClassTests : BaseTest() {
    private lateinit var myKotlinClass: MyKotlinClass

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `test callback is called when message is passed in`() {
        val captor = argumentCaptor<(data: ByteArray) -> Unit>()

        myKotlinClass = MyKotlinClass(capture(captor))

        val rawDataBytes = byteArrayOf(0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05)

        myKotlinClass.myFunction(rawDataBytes.toList())

        verify(captor, once())
    }
}
```

Using the above, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method MyKotlinClass.<init>, parameter handleSomeCallBack
```

What is the correct way to test that my callback is called, and to evaluate the data that is passed with it (`someBuffer`)?

Comment: Try to verify the callback, not your callback captor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306884/how-to-mock-lambda-with-mockito-in-kotlin

Comment: The first issue is that:
private var myCallbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<myCallBack>? = null 

Causes an error, i.e. Unresolved Reference myCallBack

Comment: i don´t work with mockito, but maybe the problem is the initialization with lateinit or do the init in setUp... another option could be change the approach, remove the lambda by constructor and use a suspend function that return the byteArray value

Comment: So, I have changed my code to resolve the initial error, but I now get a slightly different error instead... I have edited the description.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyKotlinClassTests : BaseTest() {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var handleSomeCallBack: (ByteArray?) -> Unit

    private lateinit var myKotlinClass: MyKotlinClass

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun `test callback is called when message is passed in`() {
        myKotlinClass = MyKotlinClass(handleSomeCallBack)

        val inputBytes = byteArrayOf(0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05)
        val expectedBytes = byteArrayOf(0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05)

        myKotlinClass.myFunction(inputBytes.toList())

        verify(handleSomeCallBack, once()).invoke(expectedBytes)
    }
}
```

As the callback was in my class, rather than a mock, using the captor was the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need mockito for this.
Just create lamda and store your values in list, then assert the values.

```
    @Test
    fun `test callback is called when message is passed in`() {
     val captor = arrayListOf<ByteArray>()

     val myKotlinClass = MyKotlinClass ({
        captor.add(it)
     })

     val rawDataBytes = byteArrayOf(0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05)

     myKotlinClass.myFunction(rawDataBytes.toList())

    //Assert size
    Assert.assertTrue(captor.size == 1)

    //Assert ByteArray values
}
```